# How do I resize my inputs depending on the screen size (chosen by the user in the popup)

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, spreadsheet

```js
const sheets = document.getElementById('sheets');

const siteDocument = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

const amountOfColumns = 2;

const amountOfRows = undefined;

for (var i = 0; i < amountOfColumns; i++) {
  const myNewElement = document.createElement('input');
  myNewElement.width = siteDocument
  sheets.appendChild(myNewElement)
}
for (var x = 0; x < amountOfRows; x++) {

}
```

```css
#titletext {
  font-size: 5vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="popup"></div>
    <h1 id="titletext">Excel Sheets</h1>
    <div id="buttons"></div>
    <div id="sheets"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My questions:

1. How do I get it so the width the element created depends on the width of the screen your using (the user chooses amount of inputs rows and columns), I want to make it responsive and in case there is a bunch of inputs I want to make it so it fits on the screen without having to use the scroll bar (because it's a big pain and I want to code something actually good...)
2. (You don't have to answer this question) Is vh (view-height) good for responsive web design?

UPDATE:

I want an equation that let's me have ALL the columns and rows on the screen, if I had say 10 columns it should all be on the screen (NOTE: The reason an equation is needed is because I want the columns and rows to be choosen by the user(Is this a bad approach? I'm not sure how I would do it without that)

Comment: `vh` is great for web design.  *This is my opinion.

Comment: "Is vh good for responsive web design?" We prefer to avoid opinionated responses. Maybe change it to "What are the benefits/downsides of using vh for responsive web design?"

Comment: Related to the question, its still a little unclear to me what you want.  Are you wanting the total number of rows to take up 100% of the visible viewport?

Comment: @Taplar Looking at the js code, it appears that he wants to calculate how many columns he can fit into the screen. I am quite confused, because he never specified how wide a column had to be.

Comment: If that's the case, then for starters a general css formula for the columns would be `width: calc(100vw / <numberofcolumns>)`, though that doesn't account for any padding or margins on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something with a grid and assign a repeat value of 1fr for the number of columns the user inputs for `gridTemplateColumns`.  and just set a min-width and min-height in CSS for the input to something small like 1px and it will be responsive.  Take a look at this.  You can change the number of columns and rows you have in the js code and run it and see how it auto populates and it all fits. I also did some calc math for the height of your cells based on the number of rows as well.  This should fit a fairly large and reasonable amount of inputs onto any sized screen before a scrollbar appears.  here's the fiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/uypm84e7/

```js
const sheets = document.getElementById('sheets');

const siteDocument = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

const amountOfColumns = 5;

const amountOfRows = 20;

for (var x = 0; x < amountOfRows; x++) {
for (var i = 0; i < amountOfColumns; i++) {
  const myNewElement = document.createElement('input');
  myNewElement.width = siteDocument
  sheets.appendChild(myNewElement)
  document.getElementById("sheets").style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(" + amountOfColumns +", 1fr)";
}
}
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for (var z = 0; z < inputs.length; z++) {
inputs[z].style.height = "calc((50vh/" +amountOfRows +") - 3px)";
//inputs[z].style.maxHeight = "calc((80vh/20) - 100px)";
}
```

```css
#titletext {
  font-size: 5vh;
}

#sheets {
  display: grid;
}

input {
min-width: 0px;
min-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="popup"></div>
    <h1 id="titletext">Excel Sheets</h1>
    <div id="buttons"></div>
    <div id="sheets"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```